# A probability question. There are two urns, 2 balls are picked at random from Urn I and transferred in Urn II.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, bayes-theorem

> There are two urns. In urn I there are 5 white balls and 6 black
>   balls, in urn II there are 4 white balls and 3 black balls. 2 balls
>   from urn I are picked at random and transfered in urn II. Then, two
>   balls are chosen at random from urn II.
>
> 1) What is the probability that both balls drawn from urn II are
>   black?
>
> 2) What is the probability that the balls drawn form urn II are
>   of different color if the balls selected from urn I were white?
>
> 3) What is the probability that the balls selected initially from urn I
>   are of the same color, given that the balls drawn from urn II were
>   white?

1) I tried to use the law of Bayes. Here's what I've got:

P(H1) = 2/11 (2 white balls), P(H2)=6/11 (a white and a black ball), P(H3)=3/11 (two black balls). If H1 happens, we get  6 white and 3 black balls in Urn II, if H2 - 5 white and 4 black, if H3 - 4 white and 5 black.

P(A|H1)=3/9=1/3. P(A|H2)=4/9. P(A|H3)=5/9.

P(A)=P(H1)*P(A|H1)+P(H2)*P(A|H2)+P(H3)*P(A|H3)=45/99=5/11. 
Is it correct? I have a feeling that I should have shown that there are 2 balls, not just one, but I don't know how to do it.

2) There are 6 white balls and 3 black balls in Urn II by condition. So I'm using combinations: P(A)=(6*3)/(9!/2!*7!)=3/6=1/2.

3) I'm also not sure about this one, but it seems that I have to construct a probability tree.

I would greatly appreciate it if you could help me solve it or give me a piece of advice. Thank you in advance!

Comment: $P(A\mid H_1)=\frac39\frac28$ (two balls must be black, not one). Likewise for the other $P(A\mid H_i)$

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't know why I didn't think about it earlier...

Answer (score 1):

Let $B$ denote the event that the balls taken from urn I are both black.

Let $D$ denote the event that the balls taken from urn I have different color.

Let $W$ denote the event that the balls taken from urn I are both white.

2) Let $E$ denote the event that the balls taken from urn II have different color.

Then: $$\mathsf P(E\mid W)=\frac69\frac38+\frac39\frac68=\frac12$$

3) Let $G$ denote the event that the balls taken from urn II are white.

Then: $$\mathsf P(B\cup W\mid G)=\frac{\mathsf P((B\cup W)\cap G)}{\mathsf P(G)}=\frac{\mathsf P(B\cap G)+\mathsf P(W\cap G)}{\mathsf P(G)}=\frac{\mathsf P(G\mid B)P(B)+\mathsf P(G\mid W)P(W)}{\mathsf P(G\mid B)P(B)+\mathsf P(G\mid W)P(W)+P(G\mid D)P(D)}$$

Try to work this out yourself.